# Finding all caps in columns?

Tags: sql, mysql, case-sensitive

When working with MySQL, how can I fetch all rows where the name column is all uppercase?

Since equality is case insensitive, I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column collation is case insensitive, you can override it in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column COLLATE latin1_bin = UPPER(my_column);
```

[COLLATE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM my_table REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$';`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table where binary your_field REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$'
```

Similarly:

```
SELECT * FROM table where binary your_field REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$'
```

The 'binary' casts the field to binary which is necessary for REGEXP to be case-sensitive with most data types (except binary, of course).

`[:character_class:]` notation is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) - there are several other useful character classes.

'binary' operator is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).