# Django queryset to find entries in all capital letters?

Tags: sql, django, capitalization

In raw SQL, it is possible to look through a database to find rows with a column for which the contents are written in all capital letters; that question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467589/finding-all-caps-in-columns).

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing using the Django ORM and without resorting to .raw() ?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Looks like the best way is to use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). For example,

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=['title = UPPER(title)'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression match in Django ORM. Link to documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex

Example:

```
Entry.objects.get(title__regex=r'^(An?|The) +')
```

SQL equivalents:

```
SELECT ... WHERE title REGEXP BINARY '^(An?|The) +'; -- MySQL

SELECT ... WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(title, '^(an?|the) +', 'c'); -- Oracle

SELECT ... WHERE title ~ '^(An?|The) +'; -- PostgreSQL

SELECT ... WHERE title REGEXP '^(An?|The) +'; -- SQLite
```

Using raw strings (e.g., r'foo' instead of 'foo') for passing in the regular expression syntax is recommended.

EDIT:
You can add the regular expression like:

```
Entry.objects.get(title__regex=r'^[[:upper:]]+$') #not tested
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know about the regex matching, what a great feature. If you edit your answer to include an example of using it for capitals, I'll go ahead and select it as correct. (I do know how to do this, but others might not.)